# Update object status every n seconds

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have worker class, their job is to startwhileloop. I have list of worker classes each running on their own thread. Every n seconds i should able to print the no of loops for each worker.
My intention is to print information about each worker after n seconds(e.g.20 sec)

worker1 - noOfLoops - 10
worker2 - noOfLoops - 20
workern - noOfLoops - 30
How can I achieve this.
code snippet

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IWorkerClass> workerClasses = new List<IWorkerClass>();
        for (int i = 0;i<5; i++)
        {
            workerClasses.Add(new WorkerClass("worker" + i.ToString()));
        }

        foreach(IWorkerClass wc in workerClasses)
            {
                IWorkerClass temp = wc;
                Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => wc.StartWhileLoop());
                workerThread.Start();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public interface IWorkerClass
    {
        int noOfLoops { get; set; }
        void StartWhileLoop();
    }

    public class WorkerClass : IWorkerClass
    {       
        string _name = string.Empty;
        public WorkerClass(string name)
        {
            this._name = name;
        }
        public int noOfLoops{get;set;}

        public void StartWhileLoop()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                noOfLoops += 1;                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats the question

Comment: how can i acheive this so that after n seconds i can print the status for each worker

Comment: Doesnt sound like you tried anything yet then.  How do you think you should do it

Comment: I have no idea how to achieve this, I tried to use timer but in timer i can only pass method e.g             var timer = new Timer((x) =>
            {
                printValue.print(functionToCall;
            }, null, timeSpan, interval);

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I suspect there's a much easier way, but it's hard to say exactly what without know what you're really trying to do?

Comment: my aim is to create n objects which will share the same resource as i want to learn c# thread programming

Answer (score 2):

The below code keeps your existing structure and creates a new thread which executes `ThreadReader` to ask each worker its progress every 20 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IWorkerClass> workerClasses = new List<IWorkerClass>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            workerClasses.Add(new WorkerClass("worker" + i.ToString()));
        }

        foreach (IWorkerClass wc in workerClasses)
        {
            IWorkerClass temp = wc;
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(() => temp.StartWhileLoop());
            workerThread.Start();
        }

        Thread checkerThread = new Thread(() => ThreadReader(workerClasses));
        checkerThread.Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void ThreadReader(List<IWorkerClass> workers)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (var worker in workers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{worker.name} - {worker.noOfLoops}");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(20000);
        }
    }
}
public interface IWorkerClass
{
    string name { get; set; }
    int noOfLoops { get; set; }
    void StartWhileLoop();
}

public class WorkerClass : IWorkerClass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public WorkerClass(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int noOfLoops { get; set; }

    public void StartWhileLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            noOfLoops += 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also want to fix the problem of writing/reading `noOfLoops` not being thread safe. Either through interlocked ops or through a mutex.

Comment: Did that help @delwasafewrew ?